# How to access res.locals from script instead of html

Tags: javascript, node.js, locals

I can print my `res.locals.myData` like this on client side: `<%= myData%>`

How can I use it within script? This doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var receivedData = myData
</script>
```

**EDIT**
Server output using res.locals.myData:

```
[ '83',
  { v: 294,
    f: '29 <img src="img/Gold.png">  <img src="img/Silver.png"> 94 <img src="img/Copper.png">' },
  { v: 210,
    f: '21 <img src="img/Gold.png">  <img src="img/Silver.png"> 10 <img src="img/Copper.png">' },
  { v: 1.38 } ]
```

Using `console.log(<%= sendTableData%>)`
The code is rendered as follows:

```
console.log(83,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object])
```

Which gives the

> Unexpected identifier 'Object'

error

**EDIT2**
Another approach I've tried is using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse however something happens to the string when send using res.locals. Small piece of the string: `["83",{"v":294,"f":"29` is this when it arrives: `&#34;83&#34;,{&#34;v&#34;:294,&#34;f&#34;:&#34;29`. It changes the quotation marks? Anyway I would rather avoid this method and send it as it's original data.

**Edit3** Solution was to use <%- myData%> client side (notice - instead of =) after sending data as a string.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Bit counter intuitive though but who cares :D

Comment: One more question though, does this store it as a string or as the original data format? (I need the latter but a quick test doesn't seem to work (or something else is going on))
EDIT: It seems to have become a string (was array with dictionaries). Should I not use res.locals for this? Or how could I solve this?

Comment: I think this will work but I am having another bug now. Ill report back within the hour.

Comment: Something still isn't right. The complexity seems tuned down or something. Server side object sample: ["83",{"v":294,"f":"29 <img src=\"img/Gold.png\">  <img src=\"img/Silver.png\"> 94 <img src=\"img/Copper.png\">"},{"v":210,"f":"21 <img src=\"img/Gold.png\">  <img src=\"img/Silver.png\"> 10 <img src=\"img/Copper_.png\">"},{"v":1.38}]

Becomes on client side:
83,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object].

Note the removal of '[' and ']'

Comment: Please see question again for a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following client side:

```
res.locals.myData = JSON.stringify(myData)
```

And the following client side:

```
var tableData = <%- myData%>; // For .ejs
var tableData = !{myData} // For .jade (I think)
```